# Why is the complete graph $K_2$ not Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> Why is the complete graph $K_2$ not Hamiltonian?

A graph $G$ is said to be Hamiltonian if there exists a path in $G$ which visits every vertex exactly once.
Also a path is a sequence of vertices and edges.

I am stuck on this.I see everywhere it is not Hamiltonian.
But why? Cant we take $v_1e_1v_2e_1v_1$ as a closed path from $v_1$ to $v_2$.

Also here every vertex is visited only once, only the edge $e_1$ is repeated which is allowed.

So why is it not Hamiltonian? Can someone kindly help.

Comment: Your definition is wrong. A graph is said to be [Hamiltonian](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianGraph.html) if it has a Hamiltonian cycle, [traceable](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TraceableGraph.html) if it has a Hamiltonian path. The complete graph $K_2$ is traceable but not Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a Hamiltonian cycle.  Details of paths, cycles, trails, walks, et c. depend on one's definitions.

[Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) : "A Hamiltonian cycle (or Hamiltonian circuit) is a Hamiltonian path that is a cycle."

[Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)):  "a cycle in a graph is a non-empty trail in which the only repeated vertices are the first and last vertices."

[Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path):  "A trail is a walk in which all edges are distinct."

So, no, a Hamiltonian cycle is not permitted to reuse an edge.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. If in a Hamiltonian path we are not allowed to reuse edge, how will it be different from Eulerian

Comment: @Math_Freak A Hamiltonian path or cycle is required to visit every vertex exactly once (and can't repeat edges), an Eulerian trail or tour is required to visit every edge exactly once (and is allowed to repeat vertices).

Comment: @MishaLavrov; thanks for clearing it

Answer (score 0):

A Hamiltonian graph must have a special *cycle*, and all cycles are *circuits*, and all circuits are *trails*, and all trails cannot visit an edge more than once.

Comment: But in a Eulerian graph we are not allowed to use edges too

Comment: Does it mean that Hamiltonian implies Eulerian

Comment: No, not all Hamiltonian graphs are Eulerian.